# DC Resistance of Inductors

Tags: inductor, low-pass

At the creation of a lowpass filter, I did not account the series resistance of the the inductors. Now, of course, the simulation and measured [S-Parameters](https://imgur.com/gallery/R49nK) do not fit.

In the pictures the "right_simul"-graph is the simulation with series resistance values added to the inductors.

[image: Simulation with and without DRC - S11]
[image: Simulation with and without DRC - S21]

Now my question is: Is there a way I can still get similiar results like the ones of the simulations without the series resistance values?

EDIT: I used higfrequency indcutors which were winded.

EDIT2: DRC (what should be DCR) -> series resistance

Comment: Need more information. What are you actually simulating (a schematic, please) and what are you trying to model? If your actual measurement is showing the effects of the series resistance, why would you expect to be able to simulate accurately with a model that doesn't account for the series resistance?

Comment: For what it's worth, the comparisons on the right look like a pretty good fit!

Comment: I was simulating an elliptic lowpass filter (n=6). I am not expecting to be able to simulate with a model that does not account for series resistance - I simply forgot to do it. What I am asking for is a way of getting closer to the results without the dc resistance - if possible

Comment: @OcK Don't mind Olin, he's a bit touchy. Not saying he's wrong, just touchy. Engineers tend to get ornery the longer they work with other people ;)

Comment: Use superconducting inductors that have zero resistance? Welcome to the real world! Yes, the "ideal" pictures look pretty, but you need to be able to create functional circuits from parts that you can actually get.

Comment: I guess taking power inductors instead of wired highfrequency inductors should do the job, because it seems like they have much lower resistance (~ 0.3 Ohm instead of 5-10 Ohm)

Comment: There is also an ac resistance, so you will not get ~ 0.3 Ohm.

Comment: ...power inductors will have lower self resonance frequency, so watch out for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$R_{DC} = 1.1 \Omega\$ for a \$ 1.8 \mu H\$ Coilcraft 0603LS inductor ([datasheet](https://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/0603ls.pdf)).

But the non-linear Q-factor, shows the effective resistance \$R_{Eff} = R_{DC} + R_{AC}\$ will have a more significant effect on your actual circuit.

[image: Q vs f]

Yours is not plotted, but peak is at ~8MHz for the \$ 1 \mu H\$ inductor.  Say Q = 23, which means \$X_{L} = 50.3\Omega\$.  \$R_{Eff} = 2.18 \Omega\$ as compared to stated \$R_{DC} = 0.81 \Omega\$.

So you cannot just go by \$R_{DC}\$, which is constant.  Simulations prove the concept, but the actual circuit depends on actual components.

---

The DC resistance is the resistance of the wire (constant).  It can be measured.  It is present in ac and DC circuits.

The ac resistance is due to eddy currents, hysteresis, radiation and skin effect.  It is frequency dependent.  The ac resistance does not exist in DC circuits (no frequency).

$$ Q = \frac {X_L} {R_{Eff}} = \frac {X_L} {R_{DC} + R_{ac}}$$

See [Practical Inductor](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-3/inductor-quirks/) or search google for a better explanation.

You were focusing on getting an inductor with low \$R_{DC}\$, but what you want is an inductor with a high Q (Q-factor) at your operational frequencies.

Comment: so this means, that I have to simulate it with the effective Resistance to get 'accurate' simulation results, right?

Comment: Yes.  Effective resistance depends on frequency.

Comment: Then there would be a Last question:  Why is the DC Part of the effective resistance relevant for ac?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that i.e for coilcraft they have two different product lines, like 0603HL and 0603LS where the difference is significant:

1.8uH HL -> DCR = 5.6 Ohm

1.8uH LS -> DCR = 1.1 Ohm

Maybe I should have searched first...